# SCCM 2012 Install / SQL Server 2008 R2 Connect

Tags: sql-server, sccm

We are working to install SCCM 2012 using SQL Server 2008 R2 as our Database Target.

**About our environment.**

- SCCM server is part of of "Domain A" and SQL Server is Part of "Domain B". A two trust is between the two.
- SQL Server is running CU 6 (10.50.1765).
- I've enabled: Named Pipes, TCIP, Disable Dynamic Ports and set the Port to 1433
- SQL Server is running under a named instance
- I granted the SCCM Server full access and as well as the domain account being used to do the install.
- The default collation is set to "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

To rule out firewall problems we ran a PS script to test the connectivity to the server\instance and it checked out ok.

We are getting the error.

Setup is unable to connect to SQL Server with the connection information provided. Verify the following:

The sql server and instance names are entered correctly
The specified sql server instance is not configured to use dynamic ports
If a firewall is enabled on the SQL Server, inbound rules exists to allow connection to the correct ports.
The account used to run Setup has permissions to connect to the specified SQL Server Instance.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Details of the different hotfixes required for different versions of SQL Server can be found here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg682077#BKMK_SupConfigSQLDBconfig

Minimum supported configurations include:

- SQL Server 2008 SP2 with a minimum of Cumulative Update 9
- SQL Server 2008 SP3 with a minimum of Cumulative Update 4
- SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP1 and with a minimum of Cumulative Update 6

SQL Server Express (any version) is not supported for System Center Configuration Manager 2012

Answer (score 0):

We finally figured it out.

Things we checked.

Enabled CLR with a query
No dynamic ports on any IP
Upgraded to 2008 R2 CU 6
Added the SCCM Computer as sysadmin with a query

Lastly, if you are in an environment with multiple tenants (we service several school districts) Windows SUS can not be installed and pointing to a different server. The pre-check automatically checks the same DB server as SUS. We uninstalled it (outs was pointing to an older db server) and then it worked like a champ.